# NULL value in the "key_" column of the "am_location" relation violates the NOT NULL constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, cuba-platform

I ran into the following problem: there is a “Copy” button in my interface, I have it implemented as follows:

```
    public void execute() {
        BaseUuidEntity entity = (BaseUuidEntity) metadata.getTools().deepCopy(target.getSingleSelected());
        entity.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        screenBuilders.editor(target)
                .newEntity(entity)
                .build()
                .show();
    }
```

Implementation of the deepCopy() method from the platform itself:

```
    public <T extends Entity> T deepCopy(T source) {
        CachingEntitiesHolder entityFinder = new CachingEntitiesHolder();
        Entity destination = entityFinder.create(source.getClass(), source.getId());
        deepCopy(source, destination, entityFinder);

        return (T) destination;
    }
```

As you can see, I use the deepCopy() method to copy an entity, but it doesn’t always work correctly for me. For example, I have two entries: Main and Virtual warehouse. And when copying the Main warehouse, an errors occurs at the DB level: the NULL value in the “key_” column of the “am_location” relation violates the NOT NULL constraint. I debugged and seems I understand what the problem is: the refLocation attribute in the key column is assigned a null value. And in the Location table, I have a not null constraint on KEY. And probably therefore the copied entity is not saved.
Screenshot from link [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVpo0.png)

I tried using the copy() method instead the deepCopy() method, but I started getting an IllegalStateException with unfetched attributes. Apparently the copy() method doesn’t suit me because I have nested collections for many entities and still deepCopy() method is more suitable, but it doesn’t work as it should.

I understand that I need my own implementation copy method?

Comment: Can you please share your domain class with annotations

Comment: Information isn't included in the commentary. How can I share it wtih you?

Comment: Need the code how you perform the copying. Is the key_ field filled at all before saving the new entity?

Comment: public void execute() {
BaseUuidEntity entity = (BaseUuidEntity) metadata.getTools().deepCopy(target.getSingleSelected());
        entity.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        screenBuilders.editor(target)
                .newEntity(entity)
                .build()
                .show();
    }
In method "execute" copying in progress.

Comment: @Daksharajkamal 
the oddity is that I have two records in the "Stock" table. One of them is perfectly copied and preserved, but the other is not.

Comment: @SanyaKirilloff please provide move information just edit the question and put more information how are you trying to copy and all so that I can help

Comment: @SanyaKirilloff Check what you have in the entity's `key` attribute object after `deepCopy()`

Comment: @knstvk Guess I found the problem: while copying an entity, the refLocation attribute's Key field is null, and in the am_Location table, the Key_ attribute has a constraint not null. Apparently that's why the error occurs.

Comment: @Daksharajkamal Hi! I corrected the question, added more details. Can you see? Do I understand correctly that the built-in deepCopy() method most likely doesn't suit me and I need to implement my own copy method?

Comment: @SanyaKirilloff Obviously, you can debug step-by-step the method you are trying to use and figure out why it doesn't work as expected. Or write your own deep copy method.